# How to make RichTextValue catalog full text search for Plone 4

Tags: search, text, full-text-search, plone, catalog

I created dexterity content type with Rich Text Field - "body text". I'd like to make "body text" full text searchable for my Plone 4.0.2.

I added catalog.xml in my theme, code below

I got error message from ZMI/portal/portal_catalog "body_text RichTextValue object. (Did you mean .raw or .output?) "

How can I change catalog.xml to use .output, I tried , but it doesn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You could use [plone.indexer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.indexer) and provide your own indexer inside your dexterity type to add your custom body text to the `SearchableText` index (including default title and description for example) like so:

```
@indexer(IMyTypeInterface)
def SearchableText(obj):
    return ' '.join([obj.Title(), obj.Description(), obj.bodytext.output])
```

Comment: The problem of obj.bodytext.output is, it returns HTML version of the value. It should be converted to text/plain first. I'm not sure what is the best way to do the transformation properly.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I have not encountered this issue myself, so this is just a guess.

Archetypes and others use SearchableText() index/accessor to populate the full text search index for Plone search.

You probably need to add SearchableText() method to your content type and make it return all the text concatenated which you want full text search to pick up.

Comment: A custom indexer (see Christoph's suggestion) is bettre than using a custom class and custom method.

Answer (score 0):

Christoph's suggestion of a custom indexer is a good one. You can also use this add-on: [collective.dexteritytextindexer](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/collective.dexteritytextindexer)